# How to move image to left center of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-deployment

I want to know how I can move a image when I click on that it should move to left center.

code is

```
<div id="myanm" >
    <a href="#"><img src="img/home/Services.png" class="service animated fadeInUp img_move">
        <h2 class="txt1 shadow animated fadeInUp">SERVICES</h2>
    </a>
</div>
```

css file is

```
.service{ 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    bottom:0; 
    z-index:1;
    animation-delay: 3.5s;
    height:324px; 
    width:433px;
}
```

Though already animation is applied I am unable to do click function.

Here is [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/uqykmhfb/)

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle of the current state of your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you animation starts when an element has the `service` class, you can do it in the `onclick handler:

```
<div id="myanm">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="img/home/Services.png" class="animated fadeInUp img_move" onclick="this.classList.add('service');">
        <h2 class="txt1 shadow animated fadeInUp">SERVICES</h2>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: what should i write in that function. can you help me out. thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the `onclick` attribute on the `img`. That's all you need. :)